# `AVMutableCompositionTrack.insertTimeRange` fails with error -11800

Tags: avfoundation, avcomposition

I'm creating `AVMutableComposition` from video and audio tracks:

```
func makeComposition(videoTrack: AVAssetTrack, audioTrack: AVAssetTrack) -> AVComposition {
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    /* ... */
    let compositionAudioTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio)!
    try compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(someRange, of: audioTrack, at: .zero) // Error!
    /* ... */
    return composition
}
```

and `insertTimeRange(_:of:at:)` fails with AVFoundationError -11800 `AVError.code.unknown` and undocumented underlying `NSOSStatusError` -12780. What might be the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, by the time I call `insertTimeRange` the source `AVAsset` of audioTrack got released. `AVAssetTrack` keeps **weak** reference to source `AVAsset`, so you must retain `AVAsset` in order to use `AVAssetTrack`.